pdf viewer advancing by single page in multi-page view
I'm using the okular pdf viewer on linux on an ultra-wide screen (3840 x 1600), and I like to use the 'overview' feature, where I can view three full pages side by side.
When moving forward in the document in non-continuous mode, the viewer always moves in steps of three pages, ie from showing pages 1,2,3 it goes to 4,5,6. However, I'd like to advance in single steps, e.g. going from pages 1,2,3 to 2,3,4 and so on. Is there a pdf viewer (ideally on linux), which can do something like that?
A similar feature with only two pages side-by-side would also be fine, in any case I like to have both pages visible when reading across a page transition ...
